# UIImageView.highlighted not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm encountering a strange problem:

```
UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*)[self viewWithTag:1];
[imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"open.png"]];
[imageView setHighlightedImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"close.png"]];
imageView.highlighted = YES;

NSLog(@"%u", imageView.isHighlighted);// return YES
```

But the hilighted image never appears! What's the problem with ios 7? That drive me nuts.
Can you explain me what i forgived?, that's so unintuitive

**EDIT**

---

This is not a compile problem. The question is still active. I just made a typo in my question. So will you forgive me that mistake?

I have put an image into a `UITableViewCell`, and set a image / highlighted image from IB. But when I try a toggle:

```
imageView.isHighlighted = !imageView.isHighlighted;
```

nothing appears. But if i set the `tableViewCell` to `selected = YES`. The imageView show the highlighted image.

It seems like a bug, that's so frustrating.

*** EDIT 2 ****

Actually my code look like this:

```
- (void)displayExpandedCell:(NSUInteger)viewTag isHighlighted:(BOOL)isHilighted{
    UIImageView* image1 = (UIImageView*)[self viewWithTag: viewTag];

    if([image1 isKindOfClass: [UIImageView class]]){
        image1.highlighted = isHilighted;
        image1.alpha = isHilighted? .5f : 1;
    }
}
```

The alpha actually works. But not the hilighted image.

Comment: There is no property like `isHilighted` for `UIImageView`

Comment: So why the header of UIImageView.h contain NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UIImageView : UIView {
...
@property(nonatomic,getter=isHighlighted) BOOL highlighted NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0); // default is NO

Comment: imageView.highlighted = YES;
    NSLog(@"%u", imageView.isHighlighted);// return YES

Comment: Check the spelling of the question

Comment: @MrBonjour: check the spelling of `highlighted`. It is `highlighted` not `hilighted`

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

This will sound silly, but try renaming your `imageView` to `imageView1` or anything else, this will get solved. `UITableViewCell` has a internal property named `imageView`. Your naming may be conflicting with it.